# ipad - This video is currently unavailable only in production

Tags: ipad, youtube

i have a strenge problem that my iPad dosn't play the embed you tube video directly from my site eg: http://www.tami4.co.il/products/Bubble-bar

when i try to play it on you tube add it working.

it also working in the iPad on my QA server.

some one have an idea